# Scraping tables from a website in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I was trying to extract the tables from the following link using R:
https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/1983#section=DrugBank-Interactions&fullscreen=true

I have tried the following:

```
 url <- "https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/1983#section=DrugBank-Interactions&fullscreen=true"
require(XML)
url.table <- readHTMLTable(url, which = 1, header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I get the following error:

```
     Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
 unable to find an inherited method for function ‘readHTMLTable’ for 
signature ‘"NULL"’
In addition: Warning message:
XML content does not seem to be XML: 
'https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/1983#section=DrugBank-
Interactions&fullscreen=true'
```

I am not so familiar with web scraping, is there a way to extract the tables from the above link into R? Also how can I determine in which format the data is stored; XML, JSON, etc?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm no expert but think it's because your table is not included in the page source but is loaded through js. you may have more luck taking them from the original source which is https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/DB00316#targets , this one seems contain all the data in the html source.

Comment: your `readHTMLTable` has `url.2` bur you have `url` at the top of the example

Answer (score 5):

As others have noted, the problem is that the data is loaded vs Javascript instead of in the HTML so you need a tool that will execute the JS in order to extract the info.  Ian in his answer demonstrated using RSelenium which controls a browser on your machine which accomplishes the task.  There is, in this case, another way that doesn't require RSelenium.

Using Chrome (other browsers probably do this too), you can open the Developer Tools and view the Network activity of the browser.  While this is open, if you load the link above you can see *all* of the background activity the web page engages in.  This is important because Javascript doesn't just make data appear magically, it gets it from somewhere.  This tab will let us see where the data is coming from.

What I see when I do this is:
[image: Network Activity]

This next step requires some investigative work - we need to find the step where the data is loaded.  Often this will be in a JSON format.  Most of the way down the activity list we see there are two JSON steps, one for the index and one for the data.  We can right click and open in a new tab.
[image: JSON step]

[This link](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug_view/data/compound/1983/JSON/?) contains (at first glance) all the data in the table.  We can now read this link into R and extract the tables.

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(magrittr)

json = GET("https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug_view/data/compound/1983/JSON/?") %>% 
  content(as='text') %>% 
  fromJSON()
```

`GET` is an http verb to retrieve data from a website and comes from the `httr` package.  `content` extracts the results of `GET` as text and `fromJSON` converts it into a list in R (and comes from the `jsonlite` package.  Now we have a large list which we can navigate into to find the data.

```
json$Record$Section$TOCHeading

 [1] "2D Structure"                           "3D Conformer"                          
 [3] "LCSS"                                   "Names and Identifiers"                 
 [5] "Chemical and Physical Properties"       "Related Records"                       
 [7] "Chemical Vendors"                       "Drug and Medication Information"       
 [9] "Agrochemical Information"               "Pharmacology and Biochemistry"         
[11] "Use and Manufacturing"                  "Identification"                        
[13] "Safety and Hazards"                     "Toxicity"                              
[15] "Literature"                             "Patents"                               
[17] "Biomolecular Interactions and Pathways" "Biological Test Results"               
[19] "Classification"
```

The data you're looking for is in 'Biomolecular Interactions and Pathways' (the 17th element) which leads to another data.frame which reveals the DrugBank Interactions are the third row.

```
json$Record$Section$Section[[17]]$TOCHeading
[1] "Protein Bound 3-D Structures" "Biosystems and Pathways"      "DrugBank Interactions"
```

This gives a data.frame with one column and each row is a length 1 list that contains a dataframe.

```
dbi = json$Record$Section$Section[[17]]$Information[[3]]$Table
```

We can write a function and use some `lapply`s to extract the tables.

```
extractValues = function(i,d){
  sv = dbi[d,][[1]][i,][[1]]$StringValue
  out = data.frame(Key = sv[1],Value = sv[2],stringsAsFactors = F)
  return(out)
}

dbi_Tables = lapply(1:nrow(dbi),function(d){
  out = lapply(1:nrow(dbi[d,][[1]]),extractValues,d=d) %>% 
    do.call(rbind,.)
  return(out)
})
```

And now you have a list of key/value tables.

Admittedly, it's a lot more work than a nice `rvest` call, and this JSON is *super* messy, but as a strategy for dealing with JS loaded data, it can be far faster and less fragile than RSelenium.

Comment: Wow, that's an awesome approach!

Comment: @IanKloo I do a lot of scraping at work and (often) run into this JS issue. By finding where the data comes from, I can have much more performant code.  Sometimes though, you'll find the website uses a secure API connection and you have to resort to RSelenium.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an RSelenium approach that will account for the javascript issue:

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)

#this sets up the phantomjs driver
pjs <- wdman::phantomjs()

#open a connection to it
dr <- rsDriver(browser = 'phantomjs')
remdr <- dr[['client']]

#go to the site
remdr$navigate("https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/1983#section=DrugBank-Interactions&fullscreen=true")

#get tables
tables <- remdr$findElements('class', 'table-container')

tableList <- list()
for(i in 1:length(tables)){
  x <- tables[[i]]$getElementAttribute('innerHTML') %>%
    unlist() %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_table()

  tableList[[i]] <- x[[1]]
}
```

Note that the output is a list of dataframes - this is necessary because they can all be of different lengths.

If you get errors, you may need to put some pauses in the code to account for the fact that RSelenium can get overwhelmed.  I can't think of another good way around this issue though.